# Beautifulsoup can not get content from a tag with hidden attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<a id="ember1601" role="button" href="/carsearch/book?piid=AQAQAQRRg2INmYAyjZmAMwmKOGATj2qoYBQANIAVCeAZgB6fUEsAED&amp;totalPriceShown=71.66&amp;searchKey=-575257062&amp;offerQualifiers=GreatDeal" data-book-button="book-EY-EC-Car" target="_self" class="ember-view btn btn-secondary btn-action"><span class="btn-label">
    <span aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="visuallyhidden">
            Reserve Item 1, Economy from Economy Rent a Car Rental Company at $72 total
    </span>Reserve
    </span>

</span>
</a>
```

Hi, I am new to python
I can not get the price &72 under the `<span class="visuallyhidden">`,also how can I get the href links in tag `<a>` on the first line, please help, thanks
by the way, i am using beautifulsoup lib, if other lib can help, please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # html is the code you posted

In [10]: soup.find("span", class_="visuallyhidden").text
Out[10]: '\n            Reserve Item 1, Economy from Economy Rent a Car Rental Company at $72 total\n    '

In [11]: soup.a["href"]
Out[11]: '/carsearch/book?piid=AQAQAQRRg2INmYAyjZmAMwmKOGATj2qoYBQANIAVCeAZgB6fUEsAED&totalPriceShown=71.66&searchKey=-575257062&offerQualifiers=GreatDeal'
```

if you need to extract part text from a string, you need to use regex:

```
In [12]: text = soup.find("span", class_="visuallyhidden").text

In [15]: re.search(r'\$\d+', text).group()
Out[15]: '$72'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but can not get the text, may be the website block crawler? would please help check the website: https://www.orbitz.com/carsearch?date1=03%2F08%2F2017&date2=3%2F09%2F2017&loc2=lax&locn=lax&rdus=10&selCC=%5B%22economy%22%5D&vend=

Answer (score 0):

beautifulsoup makes it possible to find a tag by its class name like that

```
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = bs_obj.find("span", class_ = "visuallyhidden") # string "class" is reserved for python itself,so bs use string "class_"
s = tag.string # that will get string inside the span
...
# you can get "$72" by regx
```

Also,bs allow you to access the tag's attr by "[]" operator.Just like

```
print(tag['href'])
```

You can see some simple example in the bs doc online.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but can not get the text, may be the website block crawler? would please help check the website: https://www.orbitz.com/carsearch?date1=03%2F08%2F2017&date2=3%2F09%2F2017&loc2=lax&locn=lax&rdus=10&selCC=%5B%22economy%22%5D&vend=  thanks